# Create thumbnail image

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

In Windows Store App (c#) I have `GridView` (100+ items). 
Each Item - `Image`. All images size = 1024*1024.
How to create thumbnail images for `GridView`?

I need something like this:

```
public BitmapImage Image
    {
        get
        {
           return new BitmapImage(new Uri("Large image from isolated storage"));
        }
    }
public BitmapImage ThumbnailImage
    {
        get
        {
           return new BitmapImage(...); //todo here Thumbnail realization 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to create **NEW** re-sized images or want to show images by re-sizing ?

Comment: I need new re-sized images. I found way like return new BitmapImage(new Uri(Path)) {DecodePixelWidth = 200, DecodePixelHeight = 200}. may you have another?

Comment: using `DecodePixelWidth` & `DecodePixelHeight` won't create new images with re-sized size, it will show images in new sized (i.e. re-sized). Do you want to save those thumbnails or just want to show thumbs in `GridView` ?

Comment: Never save. only show in 'GridView'

Comment: Then `return new BitmapImage(new Uri(Path)) {DecodePixelWidth = 200, DecodePixelHeight = 200}` is better.

Comment: but I have a problem with aspect ratio, because I cant get correct DecodePixelWidth in getter (it's 0). I try to use following ' var picture = new BitmapImage(new Uri(Path));
                var max = Math.Max(picture.DecodePixelHeight, pictureBi.DecodePixelHeight);
                if (max > 400)
                {
                    var factor = max/400;
                    picture.DecodePixelHeight = pictureBi.DecodePixelHeight/factor;
                    picture.DecodePixelWidth = pictureBi.DecodePixelWidth/factor;
                }
                return pictureBi;'

Comment: Please update your question with some more relevant code, so other can try to solve the problem.

Comment: oh, I solved it. Just set pictureBi.DecodePixelHeight = 100, or pictureBi.DecodePixelWidth = 100. But not together!